# Firefox Link Prefetching, does it work with resources?

Tags: firefox, prefetch

Reading the [Mozilla guide on prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ), I'm interested in implementing it.

My site is a single page app, so it's pointless to actually pre-fetch an entire page (incl. headers/footers/etc) when all that happens when an anchor is clicked is an ajax call is made to the backend API. Everything else is handled on the front-end.

So would it be possible to specify this API route as the prefetched link, and will Firefox use it if the call to use it is made via an ajax call?

In other words:

- Two pages: `/` and `/foobar`, going to either through addr. bar loads all content.
- Going to `/foobar` from `/` causes an ajax call to be made to `/api/foobar`, **not** `/foobar`
- Can `/api/foobar` be prefetched, and if so, will it be utilised by the underlying js?